# Javascript event flow driving me up the wall

Tags: javascript, event-handling, google-drive-api

I have a javascript which uses the Google Drive API.  Sometime it works flawlessly and other times it works only in part:

Basically it retrieves a list of files from google drive, downloads the files in a browser, put the files in another folder in google drive and finally erases the file from its original folder.

here is the portion of the script which carrys out the above process.

```
            function makeRequest() {
            console.log("make request");
            var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list({
                'q' : "'0BxTSfcTBxwlXflNjeVRZeWFQbUIzcDJMeElER1pDVEZla0NNVjhpWUpGTzY1ZDVUTS0yTFE' in Parents"}); //get only the files in a specified folder
            request.execute(function(resp) {

                var x = []; //array for revised list of file to only include those which have a suffix #FHM#
                for (i = 0; i < resp.items.length; i++) {
                    if (resp.items[i].title.substring(0, 5) == "#FHM#") {
                        x.push([resp.items[i].title, resp.items[i].webContentLink, resp.items[i].id]);
                    }
                }

                if (x.length == 0) {
                    document.getElementById("downloadButton").value = "There are no files to download";
                }


                var originalFolder = "0BxTSfcTBxwlXflNjeVRZeWFQbUIzcDJMeElER1pDVEZla0NNVjhpWUpGTzY1ZDVUTS0yTFE" //original google drive folder ID
                var processedFolder = "0BxTSfcTBxwlXfkVlYVRCdnBaMFRubWM4eUt5V0FYVEdIcHdjWDd6SFhYb3pPSjBZeFZ2T3M" // google drive folder for processed files


                //loop through all files and trigger a download event for each                     for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    console.log("download loop " + i);
                    var dlUrl = x[i][1];
                    var fileIdentity = x[i][2];
                    var fileTitle = x[i][0];//only used in the console log
                    downloadUrl(dlUrl);
                                        }

                //loop through all of final list of files and trigger the function moveFile (i.e link file to a new folder location)
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    console.log("moveFile loop " + i);
                    var dlUrl = x[i][1];
                    fileIdentity = x[i][2];
                    fileTitle = x[i][0];//only used in the console log
                    setTimeout(moveFile(processedFolder, originalFolder, fileIdentity, fileTitle),1000);

                }


                //loop through all of final list of files and trigger the function moveFile2 (i.e the one that deletes the original parent folder) 
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    console.log("moveFile2 loop " + i);
                    var dlUrl = x[i][1];
                    fileIdentity = x[i][2];
                    fileTitle = x[i][0];//only used in the console log
                    setTimeout(moveFile2(processedFolder, originalFolder, fileIdentity, fileTitle),1000);

                } 
            });
        }

        function downloadUrl(url) {
            var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
            iframe.src = url;
            iframe.style.display = "none";
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);
            console.log("download triggered");
        }



        function moveFile(processedFolder, originalFolder, fileIdentity, fileTitle) {
            //move the file to the new processed folder
            var body = {
                'id': processedFolder
            };
            var request = gapi.client.drive.parents.insert({
                    'fileId': fileIdentity,
                   'resource': body
                });
            request.execute(function(resp) {});
            console.log("file should be in new location : " + fileTitle);
        }


         function moveFile2(processedFolder, originalFolder, fileIdentity, fileTitle) {
            //this bit removes the file from the the original folder
            var request = gapi.client.drive.parents.delete({
                    'parentId': originalFolder,
                    'fileId': fileIdentity
                });
            request.execute(function(resp) {});
            console.log("file should be removed from old location : " + fileTitle);
         }
```

OK, so when I run this with 1 file to process the console.log code sections lists the events
as:

1. Download loop 0
2. download triggered
3. Movefile loop 0
4. file should be in new location : filename is XXXXX
5. movefile2 loop  0
6. file should be removed from original location

so I think that tells me the the order that the events have fired.  yet sometimes I don't get all the events completing as expected. I might have some downloads missed,  or some will move or some will still be in the original location.

If I run any one of the 3 for loops on its own it works flawlessly every time but as soon as I do all 3 it starts to fall apart and get all sorts of console error messages about being forbidden, about get request denied, deleted post request - all sorts of stuff

So.....

is this to do with the way Javascript handles events? 
do I need to somehow delay the firing of events until the previous for loop has finished? (I've tried a setTimeout for the 2nd and 3rd For loop but doesn't seems to help)
or I am missing something fundamental to how javascript works

it's like if I try and add a file to a folder before the download has physically arrived on my hard drive then it falls apart, similary if I remove a parent folder before it has finished it also falls apart.  as far as i understand Google Drive is not physically moving the file it is simply adding a label to the file.  The actual physical location in googles cloud remains unchanged throughout.

help!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Too much code for me to read on my mobile, but there are a couple of obvious issues.

1/ The use of settimeout is almost always wrong since it introduces timing errors.

2/ you have an execute call with a null callback function, followed by console.log("done "). The api call is only done within the callback, not the next line of JavaScript.

So I'd say that your guess that you've misunderstood the event v handling is correct.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I can see what you mean on the callback.  I've done a bit of reading today and can understand callbacks a bit better now. In the end I think the reason it falls over is more to do with my google drive not being able to carry out the sheer number requests to move files at the same time so I have changed it now to request a move every 2 seconds and although it take longer to process (300 odd file) it is working.